# CKEditor focusout

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, focusout

I'm trying to set focusout in CKEditor, but nothing work.

I'm using standard 4.8.0 version from cdn.

Where is the problem? I paste code below:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['note-content'].on("focusout", function(){
alert('ready');  
});
```

`note-content` is my div with `#id`.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['note-content'].getData();
CKEDITOR.instances['note-content'].setData(test);
```

works perfectly

Also tried add `cke` instance to variable, but nothing works.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['note-content'].on("blur", function() {
    alert('ready');  
});
```

Comment: @vegito15 Welcome :)